# Trouble with (ngSubmit) in Angular 2 beta

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms

I am working on a form submission in Angular 2 beta and I can get the 2 way data binding working properly with the models, but when I press enter, I cannot get it to submit when I have 3 fields when it does work with one. Here is the template file:

```
<form class="course-form" (ngSubmit)="submit()" novalidate>
  <input
    (keyup.escape)="clear()"
    ngControl="name"
    [(ngModel)]="name"
    autocomplete="off"
    autofocus
    class="course-form__input"
    placeholder="Course Name"
    required
    type="text">

  <input
    (keyup.escape)="clear()"
    ngControl="department"
    [(ngModel)]="department"
    autocomplete="off"
    autofocus
    class="course-form__input"
    placeholder="Course Department"
    required
    type="text">

  <input
    (keyup.escape)="clear()"
    ngControl="description"
    [(ngModel)]="description"
    autocomplete="off"
    autofocus
    class="course-form__input"
    placeholder="Course Description"
    required
    type="text">
</form>
Remove this: {{name}} {{description}} {{department}}
```

So when I have just the first input, I can type something in and press enter and it will submit fine. The trouble is in adding additional fields. If I type text in to all 3 boxes, however, I will see the {{}} data binding just fine. This is the typescript file, the important spot is where I go to export the class, I first set the fields to empty strings, and then when someone presses enter it should call the submit() function. I cannot see the console.log output when I have the 3 fields but I do see it with 1.

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
import { CourseService } from 'modules/course/course-service';
const styles: string = require('./course-form.scss');
const template: string = require('./course-form.html');

@Component({
  selector: 'course-form',
  styles: [styles],
  template
})

export class CourseForm {

  name: string = '';
  department: string = '';
  description: string = '';

  constructor(private courseService: CourseService) {}

  clear(): void {
    this.name = '';
    this.department = '';
    this.description = '';
  }

  submit(): void {
    const name: string = this.name.trim();
    const department: string = this.department.trim();
    const description: string = this.description.trim();
    console.log('submitted');

    if (name.length & department.length & description.length) {
      this.courseService.createCourse(name, department, description);
    }
    this.clear();
  }
}
```

For what it is worth, this is the createCourse function:

```
  createCourse(name: string, department: string, description: string): void {
    this.ref.push(new Course(name, department, description), (error: Error) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error('ERROR @ createCourse :', error);
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Angular 1 has some rules about forms and what happens when you press enter. I don't know Angular 2, but I'd be curious to see how the enter key works when your form has an actual submit button on it: either `<button type="submit">` or `<input type="submit">`.

Comment: Awesome! That totally works! I wonder why the press enter to submit gets disabled with multiple fields, anyway thanks so much!

Comment: Check the [Angular 1 docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form#submitting-a-form-and-preventing-the-default-action), it seems the behavior is the same in Angular 2. Specifically, a form w/only 1 input doesn't need a submit button for the enter key to work (for example, a search form) ... but a form w/more than 1 input needs a submit button for the enter key to work.